# Use Google Maps on Android app without having Maps App installed

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm following the sample code from Google Maps Android API v2 to develop an app. But when starting on device it tells me that `Google Maps App is missing` (if i install the Google Maps App, it works.)

However i have other apps on my device that use Google Maps, without claiming for Google Maps App installation.

How can i build a Google Maps powered app without having Google Maps installed on device?

Thanks

UPDATE:
I've found this post:

http://discgolfsoftware.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/check-if-google-maps-are-installed-on-android-if-not-direct-user-to-the-play-store/

> you must also make sure the user has the Google Maps app installed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post I wrote on how to integrate `Google Map API V2` in your application:

[Google Map API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

the deal with what you are trying to do is that you probably run the following intent:

```
 Intent navigation = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" +
                             String.valueOf(AppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLatitude())+","+
                             String.valueOf(AppObj.getInstance().currentUserLocation.getLongitude())+"&daddr="+
                             String.valueOf(task.getLatitude()) +","+ String.valueOf(task.getLongtitude())));
                     navigation.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                     startActivity(navigation);
```

But this action will try to fire up the native google maps application.

Comment: I've tried that but with the same result: Maps Android API(1637): Google Maps application is missing.
Where i have to put the "Intent" snippet?

Comment: please read the answer again, I said that if you implement the intent in the answer then the result will be that: "this action will try to fire up the native google maps application". if you dont have this application installed then it simply won't work. if you want to integrate google maps in your application the follow the link for the guide I posted.

Comment: ok, i've followed step by step the link you posted; but the app is claiming "Google Maps application is missing.". My goal is to run google maps in my app without having Maps installed on device..

Comment: if you want to integrate it inside you application then the guide is the way you should go. If you receive an error you probably didn't do all the steps correctly.

Comment: http://discgolfsoftware.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/check-if-google-maps-are-installed-on-android-if-not-direct-user-to-the-play-store/

Comment: this link, let you check if the google maps application is installed. So by pressing a place in a map you would integrate in your application it could fire an intent to get direction using the google maps application.